# Actionscript 3.0 MovieClip hit test

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, hittest

I have a MovieClip. It represents animation of jumping monster. For clearness, let's pretend there are only 2 frames: the first one occupies top left rectangle (x = 0, y = 0, w = 70, h = 70) and the second one occupies (x = 100, y = 0, w = 70, h = 70). So monster jumps from left to the right. And position of MovieClip itself is constantly = (0, 0).
I'd like to fire some event when monster is clicked by mouse.

For some reason, I have stage mouse listener, not monster mouse listener.
I wrote this code:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

private final function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    const clickPos:Point = new Point(e.stageX, e.stageY);
    // having monster:MovieClip, how do I check hitting it?
    // code below doesn't work
    // const r:Rect = new Rectangle(monster.x, monster.y,
    //                              monster.width, monster.height);
    // const hitTest:Boolean = r.containsPoint(stagePoint);
    // because r is always (0,0,70,70)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `stage.addEventListener`, apply that listener to your `monster:MovieClip` to call your onClick handler when the monster is clicked with the mouse.

```
monster.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
```

You can hit-test your monster against a point, passing in x and y coordinate.  There is a third parameter of "shapeFlag" to check against the actual pixels of the object (true) or the bounding box (false).

```
monster.hitTestPoint(x, y, true);
```

Or, hit test against another display object

```
monster.hitTestObject(obj);
```

Comment: Oops, it appeared a bit more complicated. The third argument of hitTestPoint ("shapeFlag") works correctly only for vector graphics. But my monster's frames are raster. As a consequence, hitTestPoint fires even if I click into transparent pixel of my monster. How can I solve it?